# Issue with CSS height of background image

Tags: css

The landing page image of my site keeps on getting trimmed on the top and bottom (height is limited somewhere). What I'd like is for the image to just display in aspect ratio, without height limited in normal browser.

I've wasted a good couple of hours trying changing tags in Chrome, debugging CSS, but I can not seem to get it to work.

The website is http://raiseyourglass.co.za/index.html.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, the background image doesn't command any height vs the width of the page. You can take advantage of the fact that percentage values for `padding-bottom` go off the width of the element. Try adding this to your CSS (you may need to add `!important` if the template overrides the CSS):

```
.wsite-background.wsite-custom-background {
    padding-bottom: 33.33%;
}
```